# What is the benefit of Priessman Slots in Numerical modeling?

Tags: hydrology, numerical-modelling

There is no descriptive content on the interneton what Priessman slots are and how they can be used in numerical modeling. What is the benefit of that especially in hydraulic modeling?

Comment: No content? No google results?